# search bar with restriction based on user level

Tags: php, mysql, search

I want my search bar to have restriction based on user level.The user level that i have is as follows: system_administrator,forum_admin and subforum_admin. If the user is a system_administrator, he/she can search everything.If the user is a forum_admin, he/she can search people that has the same user level as him/her.The same goes for the subforum_admin.My problem is that everytime I search using the forum_admin, I can still search everything.I tried printing the rank function result and it's returning a value.I also tried my query in php my admin and it's working fine. It's returning a result if I search a user with the same rank as the account I'm using and returning an empty result set when I tried to search a user that is not the same rank as the account I'm using.Please help.Thank you

SEARCH BAR FORM:

```
   <div class="search">
                <form method="POST" action="index.php?page=search&amp;go">

                        <input type="text" name="search" id="search-text" placeholder="Search" />
                    <input type="image"  class="search-button" src="ext/images/searchicon.png" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </form>             
            </div>
```

search.php(this is where the result will be displayed)

```
   <div id="working_area">
   <?php


   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 



    if(isset($_GET['go'])){ 

      if(preg_match("/^[  a-zA-Z]+/", $_POST['search']) === 0){ 

        echo '<div class="msg error">Invalid search query</div>';

      }else{
        $rank=rank();


        $search = search($_POST['search'],$rank);
    }   
 }



 }

 ?>     




 <?php
  foreach ($search as $s){
  ?>

 <?php
 if($s['type'] === msg ){ 
 ?>

    <div id="message" <?php>

        <div class="message">
        <h2>

        <a href="index.php?page=edit_conversation&amp;nc_id=<?php echo $s['id'];?>"><?php echo $s['name'];?></a> 
        </h2>

        </div>


    </div>
    <?php
    }else if($s['type'] === user ){
   ?>



   <div id="message">


<div class="message">
 <h2>   <?php

    if($s['profile']=="n/a"){
        echo '<img src="ext/images/profile.png" width="30" height="30" style="border-radius:5px;"/>';
    }else{
        echo '<img src="ext/images/user_images/'.$s['id'].'.'.$s['profile'].'" width="30" height="30" style="border-radius:5px;"/>';
    }
    ?> 




        <a href="index.php?page=view_profile&amp;id= <?php echo $s['id']; ?> " > <?php echo $s['firstname']." ".$s['lastname']; ?></a> 
        </h2>

        </div>


    </div>
<?php } else { 
    echo '<div class="msg error">Did not match any document</div>'; }?>
<?php
 }
?>

   </div>
```

Here is my search function:

```
    function search($search,$rank){


       $search  = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($search));

       $sql = "(SELECT nc_id AS id,nc_title AS name,null AS firstname,null AS lastname,null AS profile,'msg' AS type  FROM new_creation WHERE nc_title LIKE '%" . 
       $search . "%') 
       UNION
       (SELECT id AS id,username AS name,firstname AS firstname,lastname AS lastname,profileext AS profile,'user' AS type FROM users WHERE rank='$rank' AND username LIKE '%" . 
       $search . "%' OR firstname LIKE '%".$search."%' OR lastname LIKE '%".$search."%' ) ";


  //-run  the query against the mysql query function 
  $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());  


$search = array();  

  //-create  while loop and loop through result set 
  while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) !== false){
    $search[] = array(



        'id'            => $row['id'],
        'name'          => $row['name'],
        'type'          => $row['type'],
        'profile'       => $row['profile'],
        'firstname'     => $row['firstname'],
        'lastname'      => $row['lastname'],


  );
  }

 return $search;
 }
```

Here is my rank function:

```
      function rank(){


$result = mysql_query("SELECT rank FROM users WHERE id={$_SESSION['id']}");

if(mysql_num_rows($result) !== 1){
    return false;
}

return mysql_result($result,0);

}
```

Thank you in advance for your help...

P.S. I know that I have used deprecated functions but please bear with me I'm just a newbie in php.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the UNION? i don't see any restriction based on $rank

Comment: This seems incorrect `?page=search&amp;go` it should be `?page=search?go` then you're using POST rather than GET for `search($_POST['search']` along with a few other `&amp;`. Also make sure you've started the session. But that `?page=search&amp;go` is ambiguous. You also don't have a GET to match `?page`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. TBH, I'm having trouble making heads or tails out of this.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have started a session..it's in my init.php.. and the init.php is included in my index.php

Comment: @Vertig0 i used the union because the search bar is for searching users and messages..the $rank fetches the user level from the database

Comment: Ok, it seems a problem with your "OR" condition, you have to group it with parethensis, the query now ask, for example, for user "with rank admin or lastname like '%smith%'" if a user of a superior rank has smith in the lastname it will be returned. You have to ask for a user "with rank admin and (lastname like smith or name like smith), tell me if you dont understand me to put this in an answer

Comment: I tried changing the $_POST to $_GET but I came up with this error: Notice: Undefined variable: search in /data/web/cap/chat/core/pages/search.php on line 70 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /data/web/cap/chat/core/pages/search.php on line 70

Comment: @Vertig0 - I'll try that...  I'll inform you if it works

Comment: @Vertig0 - Thank you soooooo much... It works... just a simple parenthesis makes it work .... Thank you everyone for giving time in helping me with my problem...

Comment: Happy tp help, i let a more detailed answer anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will focus on the query here, you have this:

```
$sql = "(SELECT nc_id AS id,nc_title AS name,null AS firstname,null AS lastname,null AS profile,'msg' AS type  FROM new_creation WHERE nc_title LIKE '%" . 
   $search . "%') 
   UNION
   (SELECT id AS id,username AS name,firstname AS firstname,lastname AS lastname,profileext AS profile,'user' AS type FROM users WHERE rank='$rank' AND username LIKE '%" . 
   $search . "%' OR firstname LIKE '%".$search."%' OR lastname LIKE '%".$search."%' ) ";
```

The query to search for users is:

```
SELECT id AS id,username AS name,firstname AS firstname,lastname AS lastname,profileext AS profile,'user' AS type FROM users WHERE rank='$rank' AND username LIKE '%" . 
   $search . "%' OR firstname LIKE '%".$search."%' OR lastname LIKE '%".$search."%'
```

Now, if you search "wayne" with a forum_admin and in the DB there is a system_admin named Bruce Wayne, the query will be:

```
SELECT id AS id,username AS name,firstname AS firstname,lastname AS lastname,profileext AS profile,'user' AS type 
FROM users 
WHERE rank='forum_admin' AND username LIKE '%wayne%' OR firstname LIKE '%wayne%' OR lastname LIKE '%wayne%'
```

So, with the "OR", any user that has "wayne" in the firstname or lastname will match the query, even if the rank doesn't.

You need to change that query to:

```
SELECT id AS id,username AS name,firstname AS firstname,lastname AS lastname,profileext AS profile,'user' AS type 
FROM users 
WHERE rank='forum_admin' AND (username LIKE '%wayne%' OR firstname LIKE '%wayne%' OR lastname LIKE '%wayne%')
```

Notice the parenthesis, they will force to match the first filter AND one of the others